# I am receiving a Multidimensional array on my url via POST method, but I don't know what is array so how can I know what data is in array

Tags: php

I am receiving a Multidimensional array on my url via POST method, but I don't know what is array so how can I know what data is in array.

```
<?php

 $body = print_r($_POST);

    $myfile = fopen("smsgatewayme.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $body);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: I don't now anything that what is the name of array and what data is in array. I want to know what is in array.

Comment: Learn here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: If you want print_r to _return_ something, instead of making output directly, then you need to set the second parameter to true.

Comment: Please give me a code that can show received post data.  Becase i want to know what data is receiving via post.

Comment: I just know tha data is receiving via Post method and data type is multidimensional array.

Comment: So i want to know what is in array